# How to query subdistrict with multilinestring

Tags: qgis, postgis, spatial-database

I use postgis database and I download subdistrict shapefile of thailand from:

https://data.humdata.org/dataset/thailand-administrative-boundaries

and I have my point latitude and longitude (13.670524, 100.634237).

I try to query geom column as below query:

```
SELECT ST_ASTEXT(geom) FROM subdistrict limit 1
```

The result of geom column are multilinestring not multipolygon and data in multilinestring are coordinates; not lat, long.

[image]

I try to open shapefile in QGIS:

[image]

How do I query in subdistrict table with my point (13.670524, 100.634237)?

Comment: ...I don't get what you want to achieve with that point of yours. also, you seem to misinterpret what coordinates describe. (multi)lines and (multi)polygins are represented by an ordered sequence of coordinates (can be lat/lon) for their vertices. how did you import your data to PostgreSQL? what [CRS](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_reference_system) did you use, or what's the CRS of the shapefile (I assume EPSG:4326 / WGS84)? how would you like to query your table 'with' your point, e.g. get only the district that holds this point? ...or do you simply want to *see* it?

Comment: Sorry, I did not explain enough.

I have open district and subdistrict shapefile on QGIS, It difference

CRS of District shapefile is EPSG:4326, WGS 84 and geom column is MultiPolygon

CRS of Subdistrict shapefile is EPSG:32647, WGS 84 and geom column is Multilinestring

I can get district with below query but subdistrict cannot.

select * from district
where st_contains(geom,
                st_setsrid(st_makepoint(100.634330, 13.669349), 4326));

I would like to know Query for get subdistrict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you will need to convert those boundaries to areal representations first to be able to query them for cointaining your point. I opt for `ST_Polygonize` as it constructs exact (minimal possible) polygons from a collection of *(MULTI)LINSESTRING*s, closing any gaps of the input geometries.
I had a quick look at the data; the boundary geometries are rather tricky...
It seems every subdistrict consists of multiple *MULTILINESTRING*s, each matching only the border line to another subdistrict. The common attribute for each subdistrict is the *fid_tha_ad*, while the names for the administrative areas can have duplicates throughout the country.
The following query returns the areal representation, grouped by by *fid_tha_ad* and the non-thai admin names, that contains your point:

```
SELECT *
FROM ( 
    SELECT fid_tha_ad,
           prov_name,
           amp_name,
           tam_name,
           (ST_Dump(ST_Polygonize(geom))).geom AS geom
    FROM <your_boundary_table_name>
    GROUP BY fid_tha_ad,
             prov_name,
             amp_name,
             tam_name
) AS area
WHERE ST_Contains(
          area.geom,
          st_transform(
              st_setsrid(
                  st_makepoint(100.634330, 13.669349),
                  4326
              ),
              32647
          )
       )
```

You can add/replace the necessary column names both in the `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` clauses of the subquery. If you want to refer your original data to the results, use the *fid_tha_ad* column.
Hope that helps?

Comment: It work some area.
For area not close it cannot get subdistrict sample this 
[point (98.704324, 15.723555) ](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1N0DJ6GGMAtrvQClupnrq5u3wrvPp2zis)

Comment: Do you have website for download latest shapefile?